# discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

*при попытке сделать канал видимым только для ролей с админкой в консоли бота появляется ошибка:*

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 333, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "E:\bot\bot.py", line 54, in on_command_error
    raise error
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 859, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "E:\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role
```

---

**сам код:**

```
@bot.command()
async def lock(ctx):
    channel = ctx.channel
    author = ctx.message.author
    everyone = discord.Guild.default_role
    overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
    overwrite.send_messages = False
    overwrite.read_messages = False
    overwrite.read_message_history = False
    await channel.set_permissions(everyone, overwrite=overwrite)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Компилятор вам же указал на ошибку:

```
InvalidArgument: target parameter must be either Member or Role
```

Насколько я понял вам требуется заменить строчку

```
everyone = discord.Guild.default_role
```

на

```
everyone = ctx.message.guild.default_role
```